# How can I specify a Windows drive letter when using subversion svn+ssh

Tags: svn

How can I specify a Windows drive letter when using subversion svn+ssh?  Is it even possible?
On one system this works:

```
svn list svn+ssh://username@hostname://Preserve/svn_repository
```

But on that machine, all of svn and the repository and where ssh logs into are all on the C: drive.

On a new machine, the subversion repository is on the N: drive, but ssh and the svn command live on the C: drive.

I haven't been able to come up with a path specification that finds my repository (the repository is in this directory:   N:\Preserve\Repositories\jbp)

Note that I can access it when I am logged into the machine via this command:

```
svn list file:///N:/Preserve/Repositories/jbp
```

As an example here is a call that FAILS using svn+ssh

```
svn list svn+ssh://username@hostname/N:/Preserve/Repositories/jbp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a file based reference, [you need to use a file based URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Note that the hostname is "localhost" and if you omit it, then the URI standard will assume you meant localhost.

If you decide to attempt to access a file from a different machine; well, then you need a network URI (which may be a URL).  It is not possible to directly access a file system that lies on the other side of a network, you must use the network to access the file system on your behalf.

For Unix like systems.

```
file://localhost/etc/fstab
file:///etc/fstab
```

For Windows like systems, the colon creates issues with the URI format.  Some libraries replace the colon in C: with a pipe (or bar) like C|.  Other libraries bend the rules on Windows file URIs and allow an extra colon.

For systems that use colon replacement with bar

```
file://localhost/c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
file:///c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
```

For systems that slightly violate the URI format

```
file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
```

Wikipedia gets most of the credit on this one, but I've used file based URIs before with Subversion, they work fine (especially for creating a small repository in your own home directory to track changes on one-man hobby projects).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the file:/// way of using svn only works locally, and not over svn+ssh.  I added more information to my original post to show that it is not the file:/// svn path that I need to use.

Comment: If you want to access a file on another machine, it is not possible for your computer to directly access that file.  It must use a network protocol because the disk is not directly attached to your computer.  Even though many user interfaces hide the fact that remote shares are only your view of the remote share through a network protocol, browsing another machine's files is still network access and not local access.  You can't locally access a file that is not local, you must use a network protocol.

Comment: Since you must use a network protocol, drive letters are very often hidden as the network "name" doesn't have to include details of the file system.  HTTP servers typically restrict file access to a particular directory and their subdirectories, so a person using HTTP to access a remote machine cannot willy-nilly fetch files from sensitive areas of the computer, like C:\SYSTEM, etc.

Comment: The N: drive is a local drive on the host computer.  It is not a network drive mapped to N:

Comment: svn+ssh is a protocol that allows you to use subversion from a remote machine. It tunnels via ssh into the remote machine and then runs the svn command there and somehow pipes the response back to your remote machine. Note that my ssh access to my remote machine gives me full access to that machine, for example I can do this to look at the directory contents of the place I am trying to get ssh+svn to work at: `ssh username@host ls "N:\\Preserve"`

Comment: Not exactly.  It tunnels a SVN network protocol inside of a SSL (SSH) connection.  With svn+ssh, you must start a svnserver instance to handle the network side.  If it was truly file based commands tunneled through SSH, then you wouldn't need a server.  When working on repositories locally, I typically never start a SVN Server.  --- Using a "mapped" drive attempts to "hide" the network traffic mimicking a local file access.  The problem is that it isn't a local file access, and that will mess up certain items because certain local file operations aren't atomic over a network map.

Comment: I don't understand why you are talking about networked drives.  I am attempting to svn+ssh across the internet to my machine that has the subversion repository on it.  When the I had the repository on the C: drive svn+ssh worked fine, now that it is on the N: drive it doesn't work because it cannot find the repository.  Note that using svn+ssh this way doesn't require svnserve to be running as a service, it actually spawns an instance of svnserve on demand. Documentation about this can be found at [redbeen](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html) and search for "tunnel mode"

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer to the question, but a work around.
I gave up and just moved the repository to the C: drive.
Luckily because of how subversion works, I was able to just copy the repository, and move the old one away so I don't accidentally use it.
This makes commands like the following now work remotely, across the Internet, secured by ssh:

`svn list svn+ssh://myusername@repositoryhostname/Repositories/jbp`